# Prove $\lim_{x\to 0^+}(e^x-1+x)^\frac 2x=0$

Tags: calculus, limits

Prove $\lim_{x\to 0^+}(e^x-1+x)^\frac 2x=0$

The limit is $0$ when ${x\to 0^+}$ and $\infty$ when ${x\to 0^-}$

I have tried using logaritms and $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)^{g(x)}=e^{\lim_{x\to a}(f(x)-1)(g(x))}$, but  it doesn´t work.

Comment: $x$ approaches from the left?

Comment: The right limit does not exist.

Comment: the answer is $0$ when $x$ approaches from the right, but I don´t know when $x$ approaches from the left.

Comment: @SamGonzalez From the right, it doesn't exist. From the left the limit is zero.

Comment: I don't know why multiple people are saying the limit from the right does not exist. It's the other way around
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+as+x+goes+to+0+from+the+right+of+(e%5Ex+-+1+%2B+x)%5E(2%2Fx)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you see a limit with an exponent like that, you should strongly consider taking the logarithm of it (and usually applying L'Hopital's rule when you can, but not here).

Let $y = \lim_{x \to 0} (e^x - 1 + x)^{2/x}$. Then 
$$\ln(y) = \ln(\lim_{x \to 0} (e^x - 1 + x)^{2/x}) = \lim_{x \to 0} \ln\left((e^x - 1 + x)^{2/x}\right)$$
If you're concerned about the rigorous details of why we can pass the limit through, know that it is sufficient for a function to be continuous for us to pass a limit through it.

Now,
$$\ln(y) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2}{x} \cdot \ln(e^x - 1 + x)$$
Notice now that as $x \to 0^+$ (i.e., from the right), then $\ln(e^x - 1 + x)$ tends to $-\infty$, and since $x > 0$ when we appraoch from the right, we have $\frac{2}{x} \cdot \ln(e^x - 1 + x) \to -\infty \Rightarrow y \to 0$. Similarly, when we approach from the left side, we will have $\frac{2}{x} \cdot \ln(e^x - 1 + x) \to \infty$ so that $y \to \infty$.

In summary, the limit as we appraoch from the right is $0$, where as the limit diverges when you appraoch from the left.

Comment: But from the left $e^{x}-1+x<0$, $\log$ is not defined, and I made the mistake as well, I have deleted my answer.

Comment: If we view the logarithm over the complex numbers, then if $e^x - 1 + x < 0$, then we have $\ln(e^x - 1 + x) = i\pi + \ln|e^x - 1 + x|$ and we still get something that diverges to infinity in a sense. You're right though, over the reals we'd need a more solid argument for why the limit diverges...